# Class does not name a type with header guard

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, include-guards, platformio

Due to error, I needed to implement a header guard in my Header file and Cpp since I have never used it before I don't know what went wrong because on some classes it works and on one it just won't... Originally the problem was bigger, but I think I narrowed it down to the origin of the problem.

**LedHandler.h**

```
#ifdef LED_HANDLER_H
#define LED_HANDLER_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <FastLED.h>

/* #include "Led/LedFunction.h"
#include "Led/LedStates.h"
#include "Led/Fading.h" */

class LedHandler {
  public:
    LedHandler(int length, uint16_t pin);
    void clear();
    void show();
    void setColor(int s, int r, int g, int b);

    Adafruit_NeoPixel getStrip();
    int getLength();
  private:
    /* LedStates &currentState;
    LedStates &targetState;
    Fader<LedStates> &ledFader; */

    int length;
    Adafruit_NeoPixel strip;
    CRGB* leds;
};

#endif
```

**LedHandler.cpp**

```
#ifdef LED_HANDLER_H
#define LED_HANDLER_H

#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <FastLED.h

#include "Handlers/LedHandler.h"


LedHandler::LedHandler(int length, uint16_t pin) {
...
}
...
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#define FASTLED_ESP8266_NODEMCU_PIN_ORDER

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Scheduler.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#include "Tasks/WifiTask.h"
//#include "Tasks/Networking/UDPTask.h"

//#include "Handlers/GsonHandler.h"
#include "Handlers/LedHandler.h"

LedHandler ledHandler(60, D6);
```

**Error**

```
src\main.cpp:14:1: error: 'LedHandler' does not name a type
 LedHandler ledHandler(60, D6);
 ^
*** [.pio\build\nodemcuv2\src\main.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You have a typo in the `LeadHandler.cpp`  `#include <FastLED.h`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by walnut in comments, first issue is that `#ifdef` should be `#ifndef`. Now this directive can never be evaluated to `true` (because this macro is not defined anywhere).

Also, you shouldn't ever put include guards in your `cpp` file. As the name suggests, you use them to protect files that included in other files, and `cpp` files should never be included anywhere.

Now, with include guard in your `cpp` file, the following happens:

1. Code is read from top to bottom
2. `ifndef` is encountered, it is `true` (`LED_HANDLER_H` is not yet defined)
3. `LED_HANDLER_H` is defined
4. Other headers are included
5. "Handlers/LedHandler.h" is included
   Now, it's important what `#include` directive does. It's a simple copy-and-paste of the file content into another file.
6. `#ifdef LED_HANDLER_H` from inside `LedHandler.h` is checked, and it's `false` (this macro is already defined in step 3)
7. **The whole content of `LedHandler.h` is skipped due to include guard.**

Comment: I had different names of those before, but when I remove the guard from the .cpp I get the following error: ``src\Handlers\LedHandler.cpp:7:1: error: 'LedHandler' does not name a type
 LedHandler::LedHandler(int length, uint16_t pin) {``

Comment: @Maxdola Did you change `ifdef` to `ifndef` in header?

Comment: Yes and I actually overread that Sorry, and this actually fixed this problem Thanks.

Comment: @Maxdola That was editted in later, after walnut's comment ;) Glad I could help.